# Prove that such analytic function exists

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm going through the **Complex variables** by *Murray R. Spiegel* (Schaum's outline series) and I stack on a problem 69 from chapter 4:

Let $P$ and $Q$ be continuous and have continuos first partial derivatives is a region $\mathcal{R}$. Let $C$ be any simple closed curve in $\mathcal{R}$ and suppose that for any such curve
$$\oint\limits_C Pdx + Qdy = 0$$
a). Prove that there exists an analytic function $f(z)$ such that $Re\{f(z)dz\}=Pdx+Qdy$ is an exact differential.

b). Determine $p$ and $q$ in terms of $P$ and $Q$ such that $Im\{f(z)dz\}=pdx+qdy$ and verify that $\oint\limits_C pdx + qdy=0$.

*My thoughts:*

If $f(z) = u(x,y) + i v(x,y)$, then
$$f(z)dz = (udx-vdy) + i(vdx+udy).$$
Since,
$$Re\{f(z)dz\}=udx-vdy=Pdx+Qdy,$$
the best candidates for $u$ and $v$ are $P$ and $-Q$ correspondingly. Thus, we need to check that $f(x, y) = P(x,y) - iQ(x,y)$ is analytic, i.e. check Cauchy-Riemann equations (as $P$ and $Q$ have continuos first partial derivatives). We immediately get
$$\frac{\partial P}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}$$
using the fact that the given integral equals zero for any closed curve. (Moreover, gradient theorem tells us that $Pdx+Qdy$ is an exact differential as well). However, I have no idea how to show that
$$\frac{\partial P}{\partial x} = - \frac{\partial Q}{\partial y}.$$

Comment: I don't think $\frac{\partial P}{\partial x} = -\frac{\partial Q}{\partial y}$ should be true. Take $P = x$ and $Q = y$ (or, more generally, take $(P,Q) = \nabla F$ for any $F$ such that $\Delta F\ne 0$).

Comment: Yes, basically, it's the same as stating that if Pdx+Qdy is an exact differential, then P and Q are harmonic, which is not necessary true. But I don't see where my logic is wrong.